# Fixing combined cell justification

Tags: tables, justification

I'm trying to fix a table I've made. The code I have is

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
% !BIB program = biber

\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Calibri}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=3.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[table,usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|p{3cm}|l|l|}
    \hline
    \rowcolor{BurntOrange}
    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\color{white} \textbf{EDEBÉ}} \\
    \hline
    \cellcolor{Cyan} & \cellcolor{Cyan!80}
    9.1. Elementos básicos de geom. & \cellcolor{Cyan!80} 9.7. Polígono regulares. \\
    \cellcolor{Cyan} & \cellcolor{Cyan!60} 9.2. Rectas. & \cellcolor{Cyan!60} 9.8. Tamaño y forma. \\
    \cellcolor{Cyan} & \cellcolor{Cyan!80} 9.3. Semirrectas y segmentos. & \cellcolor{Cyan!80} 9.9. Traslación y giro. \\
    \cellcolor{Cyan} & \cellcolor{Cyan!60} 9.4. Construcciones con regla y compás. & \cellcolor{Cyan!60} 9.10. Simetría. \\
    \cellcolor{Cyan} & \cellcolor{Cyan!80} 9.5. Geometría con recursos digitales. & \cellcolor{Cyan!80} 9.11. Semejanza. \\
    \multirow{-6}{*}{\cellcolor{Cyan} \textcolor{white}{\textbf{Unidad 9.} Geometría en el plano.}} & \cellcolor{Cyan!60} 9.6. Polígonos. & \cellcolor{Cyan!60} 9.12. Mosaicos. \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

And its output is shown in the next picture.
[image: Output table]

As you can see, the text inside combined cells doesn't adjust to width specification. How can I fix it? I can't figure how to make that line broke into 2 lines. I tried `parbox` but just not good enough the result:

[image: sample with parbox]

PS: That is going to be a long table later. So probably it would be better if I settle width for each column and making text to autofix inside? But how to force alignment then?

**---- UPDATE ----**

1. Added preamble in code block.
2. Changed personalized colors to `xcolor` gamma.
3. Since colors are not the topic, I'm not updating images.

Comment: `{=}` instead of `{*}` as the second argument to the  `\mulitorw` command should get you closer to the expected output.

Comment: @leandriis It broke. I'm trying to show how the output gets... Just give me one minute to figure out how to add the pic in answers box.

Comment: Output with that suggestion in this drive file: 
[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1I2zdcW-eFxzCoHlhdcLFdGEf1nnprMOl/view?usp=share_link)
There you can check, @leandriis

Comment: @Zarko , F. Pantigny... Thanks for your answers. Both are options which use commands unknown to me, so I still have to document myself about them. Since that will become a larger table soon, I also have to figure out if your options properly adjust and align long text in cell. But they both seems really nice options.

The best option I got is quite less fancy. I will post it as an possible answer (although I'm not sure if that is the best way to post it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{p{3cm}ll}[vlines]
\CodeBefore
    \rowcolors{2}{cyan!60}{cyan!30}[cols={2,3}]
\Body
    \Hline
    \Block[fill=purple]{1-3}{\bfseries\color{white} EDEBÉ}
        &                                           &   \\
    \Hline
    \Block[fill=cyan!60]{6-1}{\textbf{Unidad 9.} Geometría en el plano.}
        &   9.1. Elementos básicos de geom.         &   9.7. Polígono regulares.    \\
        &   9.2. Rectas.                            &   9.8. Tamaño y forma.        \\
        &   9.3. Semirrectas y segmentos.           &   9.9. Traslación y giro.     \\
        &   9.4. Construcciones con regla y compás. &   9.10. Simetría.             \\
        &   9.5. Geometría con recursos digitales.  &   9.11. Semejanza.            \\
        &   9.6. Polígonos.                         &   9.12. Mosaicos.             \\
    \Hline
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations.

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

[image]

- you nor provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), so we haven't any information about <our document preamble (used document class, page layout, definition of colors etc.)
- In image of table is produced by MWE, at which I anticipate that in your document are used
  -`article` document  class

  - `geometry` package (for page layout)
  - instead of unknown named colors are used default colors available at any `xcolor` option
- For simplicity and shortness of table coda is used `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{tblr}{vlines,
             colspec = {X[0.3, l, bg=cyan!60] *{2}{X[bg=cyan!30]}},
             row{1} = {font=\bfseries, fg=white, bg=purple},
             row{even[2-Z]} = {bg=cyan!60}
            }
    \toprule
\SetCell[c=3]{c}    EDEBÉ       
    &                                           &   \\
    \midrule
\SetCell[r=6]{m}     \textbf{Unidad 9.} Geometría en el plano.
    &   9.1. Elementos básicos de geom.         &   9.7. Polígono regulares.    \\
    &   9.2. Rectas.                            &   9.8. Tamaño y forma.        \\
    &   9.3. Semirrectas y segmentos.           &   9.9. Traslación y giro.     \\
    &   9.4. Construcciones con regla y compás. &   9.10. Simetría.             \\
    &   9.5. Geometría con recursos digitales.  &   9.11. Semejanza.            \\
    &   9.6. Polígonos.                         &   9.12. Mosaicos.             \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

By the way, after a long session of edit-n-try, I came up with this low-fancy option.

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
% !BIB program = biber

\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Calibri}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=3.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[table,usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}


\begin{document}
    
    
    \begin{tabular}{|c|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{6cm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{6cm}|}
        \hline
        \rowcolor{BurntOrange}
        \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\color{white} \textbf{EDEBÉ}} \\
        \hline
        \cellcolor{Cyan} & \cellcolor{Cyan!80}
        9.1. Elementos básicos de geom. & \cellcolor{Cyan!80} 9.7. Polígono regulares. \\
        \cellcolor{Cyan} & \cellcolor{Cyan!60} 9.2. Rectas. & \cellcolor{Cyan!60} 9.8. Tamaño y forma. \\
        \cellcolor{Cyan} & \cellcolor{Cyan!80} 9.3. Semirrectas y segmentos. & \cellcolor{Cyan!80} 9.9. Traslación y giro. \\
        \cellcolor{Cyan} & \cellcolor{Cyan!60} 9.4. Construcciones con regla y compás. & \cellcolor{Cyan!60} 9.10. Simetría. \\
        \cellcolor{Cyan} & \cellcolor{Cyan!80} 9.5. Geometría con recursos digitales. & \cellcolor{Cyan!80} 9.11. Semejanza. \\
        \multirow{-8}{*}{\cellcolor{Cyan} \parbox{2.25cm}{\textcolor{white}{\bf Unidad 9. Geometría en el plano.}}} & \cellcolor{Cyan!60} 9.6. Polígonos. & \cellcolor{Cyan!60} 9.12. Mosaicos. \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    
\end{document}
```

And its result would be:

[image: table output]

As I said in previous comment, is not as fancy as proposals made by @Zarko or  @F. Pantigny (the alingment/adjustment is akward in my code) but until I trully understand those codes, is what I got.